# How to use sign in with email and password with Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, formik

This is going to be my longest post on Stack Overflow and I'm not proud of it. The focus should be on the *first two* code blocks in which I define the functions handling firebase. The other bits are just a sanity check that I am not missing anything simple.

The problem is that my form won't be submitted (and the functions inside of the onSubmit don't even run). After clicking the 'submit' button, I'd like to register a user to Firebase with email and password. That doesn't work as it stands.

```
async createUserProfileDocument(user, additionalData) {
    if (!user) return
    const userRef = this.firestore.doc(`users/${user.uid}`)
    const snapshot = await userRef.get()
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
      const { displayName, email, photoURL } = user
      const createdAt = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
      try {
        await userRef.set({
          displayName,
          email,
          photoURL,
          createdAt,
          ...additionalData,
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('error creating user: ', error)
      }
    }
    return this.getUserDocument(user.uid)
  }
```

```
export const Register = () => {
  const history = useHistory()

  async function writeToFirebase(email, senha, values) {
    try {
      const { user } = await firebaseService.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha)
      firebaseService.createUserProfileDocument(user, values)
      history.push('/')
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error: ', error)
    }
  }

  function onSubmit(values, { setSubmitting }) {
    values.displayName = values.user.nome
    writeToFirebase(values.user.email, values.user.senha, values)
    setSubmitting(false)
  }

  return (
    <div className="booking">
      <Formik
        initialValues={initialValues}
        validationSchema={Yup.object({ ...validationService.generateBasicUserSchema() })}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <Form>
          <EWUserBasicDataFields />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      </Formik>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Do some testing, remove `validationSchema` and see if you can submit the form. If you can, the problem is that the form is invalid. Also check in the console to see if you don't have any errors

Comment: @Vencovsky spot on! thank you

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments

Do some testing, remove `validationSchema` and see if you can submit the form. If you can, the problem is that the form is invalid. Also check in the console to see if you don't have any errors.